# MySQL with Asp.net: Out of memory (Needed 134217700 bytes)

Tags: asp.net, mysql

My Query is as Below,
This works perfectly after removing distinct from "DISTINCT permissionid" clause of top Query.

```
SELECT modulename, 
   Group_concat(DISTINCT permissionid) Permissions FROM   licensedproductpermission 
   JOIN vw_licensedproduct USING (licensedproductid) 
   JOIN modulepermission USING (permissionid) 
   JOIN module USING (moduleid) WHERE  ( permissionid IN (SELECT permissionid 
                      FROM   rolepermission 
                      WHERE  roleid IN (SELECT roleid 
                                        FROM   userrole 
                                        WHERE  userid = 14)) ) GROUP  BY modulename UNION SELECT modulename, 
   permissionid FROM   modulepermission 
   JOIN module USING (moduleid) WHERE  permissionid IN ( 159 ) 
   AND ( permissionid IN (SELECT permissionid                               FROM   rolepermission 
                          WHERE  roleid IN(SELECT roleid 
                                           FROM   userrole 
                                           WHERE  userid = 14)) ) UNION SELECT modulename, 
   permissionid FROM   modulepermission 
   JOIN module USING (moduleid) WHERE  moduleid IN ( 160, 98 ) UNION SELECT modulename, 
   permissionid FROM   licensedproductpermission 
   JOIN vw_licensedproduct USING (licensedproductid) 
   JOIN modulepermission USING (permissionid) 
   JOIN module USING (moduleid) WHERE  permissionid = 1
```

But with DISTINCT permissionid this starts throwing exceptions after some time. After mySQL restarts it again works for some time. At the time of open connection we are setting server vars like;

```
'Open Connection
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function OpenConn(conn As MySqlConnection) As MySqlConnection
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Open()

        Dim sSetSql As String = _
           "SET SESSION tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; " & _
           "SET SESSION max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; " & _
           "SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1; " & _
           "SET SESSION GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=1048576; " & _
           "SET NET_WRITE_TIMEOUT=99999; " & _
           "SET NET_READ_TIMEOUT=99999; " & _
           "SET SESSION WAIT_TIMEOUT=99999;"

        clsDBAccess.cmdExecuteQueryWithoutLog(conn, sSetSql, Nothing)
        Return conn
    End Function
```

An at the time of connection closing..

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub CloseConn(conn As MySqlConnection)
        If Not IsNothing(conn) AndAlso conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
        conn = Nothing
        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced)
        GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced)
    End Sub
```

Request to suggest where are we leaking memory, as this works for some after restarting of MySQL.

Comment: Can you post your table definitions, along with an explain of the query with and without the DISTINCT? Also, are the number of processes going up with time?

Comment: Thanks Kickstart, We have proper Indexing, this query is very fast and executed once for every login. We are not asking for query optimization, seems we are leaking memory or we need to set some Global Variables. Still if you feel Index and Table Definition plays role in Memory leak or above issue, will try to access to get those and post here, kindly quote!

Comment: A memory leak is always possible, but I would expect such a leak to occur to others very regularly as well. Is this query run often on request, or sequentially in a batch job? Your tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size both seem very large to me (as does a 1mb GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN). I beleive that MySQL should resort to disk storage if it breaches these limits.

Comment: Excuse the link to another stack site, but this might help with tracing down the setting - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/why-does-mysql-say-im-out-of-memory